# Simple solutions to linear systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, signal-processing

I am facing a problem which I think boils to down sparse decomposition. However, the solvers I am using don't seem to be producing sensible results and I'm wondering if I'm perhaps applying the wrong algorithm.

The problem can be expressed as follows: solve the tuples $(x_{ij}, y_{ij})$ for $1\leq i\leq  n$ and  $1\leq j\leq m$ where:

- $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$ are all non-negative integers
- The ratio $\frac{x_{ij}}{y_{ij}}$ is pretty constant; maybe it varies between 0.5 and 1.5 or so
- If $x_{ij}$ is zero then $y_{ij}$ is zero and vice-versa
- For every $j$ we know $\mathbf{a}_j=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{ij}, y_{ij})$
- For every $i$ we know $\mathbf{b}_i=\sum_{j=1}^m (x_{ij}, y_{ij})$

The above problem isn't well-posed since we may have infinite possible solutions. What we want is to find the one that represents the "simplest" decomposition. For example, given the following

- $\mathbf{a}_1 = (123, 100)$, $\mathbf{a}_2 = (123, 200)$, $\mathbf{a}_3 = (400, 300)$
- $\mathbf{b}_1 = (123, 100)$, $\mathbf{b}_2 = (523, 500)$

You can see that $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{b}_1$ are equal. So if we set

$$
(x_{ij}, y_{ij}) = \begin{cases}
(123, 100)&\text{for }i=1, j=1\\
(0, 0)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then we've solved those two. Then we can see that $\mathbf{a}_2+\mathbf{a}_3==\mathbf{b}_3$  so we can add a couple more clauses and we are done:

$$
(x_{ij}, y_{ij}) = \begin{cases}
(123, 100)&\text{for }i=1, j=1\\
(123, 200)&\text{for }i=2, j=2\\
(400, 300)&\text{for }i=2, j=3\\
(0, 0)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I have a couple of thousand cases of this problem to solve, where $n$ and $m$ range from 1 up to around 60. So not huge but it of course does get more complex than the above! The values of $\mathbf{a}_j$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ are often six or eight digits long, and I have the feeling that there is a lot of information encoded in the digits that I can leverage to my advantage.

What I have done so far is to frame this problem as finding the ***sparsest*** solution. I've discovered algorithms like positive orthogonal matching pursuit and extensions to a multi-matching cases, and they do give me sparse solutions. However, they also miss really obvious matches like the $\mathbf{a}_1 == \mathbf{b}_1$ case above. I can filter such obvious solutions out before running my solver, but I'm wondering if I'm actually using the wrong algorithm. Matching pursuit looks to start with the waveform that gives the *largest* product with the signal, when really I care about *the closest*.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: So, you want to find two matrices? Try to write in matrix form, which is more succinct.

Comment: I'm looking to find the x that minimises _something_ given that Ax = b, A and b are known, x is a matrix of two columns, the entries are positive integers, and are also correlated as I described. But I'm not sure what that something is. I've tried minimising the l0-norm of x but either it's the wrong thing to minimise, or I'm using the wrong algorithm.

Comment: Why are some matrices uppercase and others lowercase?

Comment: This is kind of long. Try to break into sections. Ideally, at the very top is the mathematical essence of the problem and one can determine within 30 seconds whether one is qualified to answer. If the reader is interested, then he or she can read the rest — motivation for the question, what your thoughts are, etc.